# How can I analyse and reduce the size of my browserify generated files?

Tags: javascript, performance, browserify

I have a small application using browserify, which, it has recently come to my attention, has a very large bundle.

**Are there tools to analyse a browserify file and work out where the bulk of the file size is coming from?**

How can I the reduce size of my browserify generated files?

Comment: Er, why the vote to close? JS community seems to share the problem and appreciate the answer @mantoni gave https://twitter.com/mikemaccana/status/577878656133005313

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out disc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/disc

It analyses your bundle and show a graph ordered by file count or size.

[image]

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for. I found out I have around 100K of country data in my bundle. Thanks muchly!

Comment: @yo.ian.g yes, disc can be invoked from the command line, and yes, it can generate an html file on the command line, but can it actually output to the command line in a format that can be read on the command line?